# How to stop ReSharper from formatting multi-line comments in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, resharper

I recently got JetBrains ReSharper and have been using it for C++. However, I have a major pet peeve and cannot seem to find any documentation or customization on this. When I make a multi-line comment using a backslash and asterisks, it inserts asterisks on every line and does not keep the spacing I had, like Visual Studio did before I got ReSharper. Here's what I mean:

ReSharper turns

```cpp
/*
 This on its own line
*/
```

into

```cpp
/*
 * This on its own line
 */
```

To add to this, ReSharper also does not keep my spaces from line to line as VS did. For example, in the comment

```cpp
/*
 This is a function, and these features are TODO
   > Thing 1
   > Thing 2
   > Thing 3
*/
```

vanilla VS would not make me manually press space for the `> Thing x` text, but would instead keep the indentation from line to line. In ReSharper, I have to not only clear the annoying `*` at the start of every comment but then manually press space for my indentation with every single line.

My question is how to change this to let VS handle my comment formatting since this is very annoying, especially with larger comments. And for anyone concerned with a style guide, my class has a VERY strict style guide; I would be counted off points on assignments for letting ReSharper keep its default formatting.

Thank you for any help that can be provided. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the newest version of ReSharper (as of December 2, 2019).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "ReSharper turns ... into ...". If you don't want R++ to insert '*' after Enter in multi-line comments, turn off "Insert * on Enter after /*" in ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Behavior.

I agree with your second comment that this behavior should be fixed, I've filed a tracking request - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-28345. As a workaround, disable "Smart indent on enter" on the same options page.

Comment: Both parts of your answer fully answer both parts of my question. I made this the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Second issue should be fixed in the 2019.3 release which is out today.